# Get 5 oldest Objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I have an array of objects of the form:

```
{productID: '15', name: 'Pepsi', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-12-21T17:42:34Z'}
```

I want to find the 5 oldest items by comparing the `dateAdded` strings. I have tried a few inefficient loops and failed with `reduce()`, but I feel there's a more efficient way. How can I accumulate the 5 oldest items?

Comment: you mention `efficent way` how big is your array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a simple sort/slice will do it - the format of the date means you can just do a `localeCompare` in your sort callack ... `

```js
const array = [
    {productID: '15',name: 'Pepsi',category: 'food/beverages',dateAdded: '2015-12-21T17:42:34Z'},
    {productID: '13',name: 'Coke',category: 'food/beverages',dateAdded: '2015-12-20T17:42:34Z'}
];
const top5 = array
    .sort(({dateAdded: a}, {dateAdded: b}) => a.localeCompare(b))
    .slice(0, 5);
console.log(top5);
```

Comment: Wow, I was overthinking this and completely overlooked sorting. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can Sort by `datetime` like below.

```
array.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => 
    new Date(firstEl.dateAdded).getTime() - new Date(secondEl.dateAdded).getTime())
    .slice(0, 5);
```

```js
 const array = [
      { productID: '0', name: 'Pepsi', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-12-21T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '1', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-10-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '2', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-11-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '3', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-08-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '4', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-01-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '5', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2015-03-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '6', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2016-10-20T17:42:34Z' },
      { productID: '7', name: 'Coke', category: 'food/beverages', dateAdded: '2017-10-20T17:42:34Z' },
    ];
    
const newArr = array.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => new Date(firstEl.dateAdded).getTime() - new Date(secondEl.dateAdded).getTime()).slice(0, 5);
    
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the items by `dateAdded` then take the top 5, which should be the oldest

Answer (score 0):

Solutions sorting the array will likely modify the order of elements in the array. A non–mutating method is to grab the value to sort on and the related index, that way you can get the required elements without modifying the source array, e.g.

```js
// To generate random data
function genRandomData(num = 10) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i=0; i<num; i++) {
    result.push(
      {productID: i,
       dateAdded: new Date(Date.now() + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1e10).toISOString()}
    );
  }
  return result;
}

// Return n oldest entries in data
function getOldest(n, data) {
  let indexes = data.map((obj, i) =>
    ({index:i, date: obj.dateAdded})
  ).sort( // Oldest first
    (a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date)
  );
  return indexes.slice(0,n).map(obj => data[obj.index]);
}

// Random data from genRandomData()
let data = [
  {
    "productID": 0,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-23T17:41:20.135Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 1,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-13T14:35:25.296Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 2,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-14T20:39:27.210Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 3,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-30T16:50:00.163Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 4,
    "dateAdded": "2022-02-28T22:04:53.106Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 5,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-12T03:08:29.874Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 6,
    "dateAdded": "2022-02-18T07:13:25.202Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 7,
    "dateAdded": "2022-04-10T17:35:30.277Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 8,
    "dateAdded": "2022-01-29T11:43:22.832Z"
  },
  {
    "productID": 9,
    "dateAdded": "2022-03-18T06:29:28.833Z"
  }
];

// Oldest 3 elements of data
console.log(getOldest(3, data))
```

Note that the objects in the original array are referenced by the returned array, so modifying them also modifies the originals.